# End to end Testing / Run Selenium IDE .json file using webdriver node.js

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, end-to-end, selenium-server

I have installed `Selenium extension` of google Chrome [Selenium IDE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd), so I can record my tests and save the test file as `.side` which is a `json` file. It contains

`{id , command , target , value}` .

```
{     "id": "70a08bcc-b351-4ec6-b64d-f833f09adfa2",
      "name": "Untitled Project",
      "url": "http://example.io",
      "tests": [
        {
          "id": "0b5184ff-4873-459b-b55b-77d56ebf5f6e",
          "name": "Untitled",
          "commands": [
            {
              "id": "35b40ae7-1ada-46d9-8c65-d8faaf1af753",
              "command": "open",
              "target": "/",
              "value": ""
            },
            {
              "id": "0e0bd8b3-4301-4ac6-8cd6-4b01fa94f68d",
              "command": "type",
              "target": "name=login",
              "value": "test@tets.io"
            },
            {
              "id": "078da69d-eec3-44b8-b793-53b401a18ac4",
              "command": "clickAt",
              "target": "//div[@id='cloud-ui']/div/div[3]/div/button/span",
              "value": "24,17"
            }...
```

I would like to know if there is solution to run the test file automatically using `JavaScript`, for example a plugin that reads the file and execute the commands ?

If no, what about create my own JavaScript function that fetch the JSON objects `{id, command, target, value}`  and execute the commands?

for example:

```
   {
      "id": "512a84b8-c3b0-4cb6-88b4-025d28502f1f",
      "command": "clickAt",
      "target": "css=li.active > a",
      "value": "18,62"
    }
```

we can run it using `selenium-webdriver`

```
  driver.findElement(By.css("li > a > span")).click();
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-side-runner

Comment: Can the side runner also run parametrized test? (ie: I want the test to loop on a few buttons and do the same thing, but I need to provide names of buttons in a list)